# Can a query within quotes be classified as an SQL Injection?

Tags: sql-injection

I am working on a project where I attack with several tools like sqlmap, some applications and I log the queries made to the database.
I have used sqlmap to attack one application but although I know these queries are coming from sqlmap so they should be attacks I am not sure they could work.

Here is an example of such queries.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1842-1841';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1.1jUVb';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1) AND 8368=8230 AND (9937=9937';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1) AND 9401=9401 AND (9316=9316';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1 AND 6958=6015';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1 AND 9401=9401';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1 AND 3154=1482-- mJGo';",,,,,,,,,""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1 AND 9401=9401-- GxcI';",,,,,,,,,""
```

As you can see the injected part is **within** the single quotes. Does this mean that it will always be considered as a string by the database? If yes, doesnt that mean that the Logical AND will never be interpreted correctly, thus this query is **not** going to be successful no matter what?

Are there some cases where the above is an actual working attack?
It troubles me since Sqlmap tries these queries I imagine that they could actually work under some circumstances but I do not see how.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are only within quotes because your application put them in quotes.

Imagine the following code

```
$sql = 'select * from passwords where PIN ='.$pin
```

Injecting`1 AND 9401=9401`

gives you

```
$sql = 'select * from passwords where PIN = 1 and 9401=9401'
```

Comment: ok so that means that due to the application uses single quotes this is interpreted as a string? and that if I was attacking a different application it could work?
correct?